# How scroll down EditText in Android

Tags: android, sdk, scroll, android-edittext, scrollbar

how make auto scroll in EditText?

the scrollTo(x,y) dont works... =/

```
final EditText edittext1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final EditText edittext2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    //edittext1.setKeyListener(null);
    edittext2.requestFocus();

    edittext2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                getWindow()
                        .setSoftInputMode(
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

                edittext1.setText(edittext1.getText() + "\n"
                        + edittext2.getText() + "\n\n");

                funcoes(edittext2.getText().toString());

                edittext1.scrollTo(0, edittext1.getLayout().getLineCount());

                edittext2.setText("");

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    });
```

I've tried colocoar within a ScrollView, but does not work very well. 
Has some way to do this scroll in EditText?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this:

```
edittext1.scrollTo(0, edittext1.getLayout().getLineCount());
```

with this:

```
int y = (edittext1.getLineCount() - 1) * edittext1.getLineHeight(); // the " - 1" should send it to the TOP of the last line, instead of the bottom of the last line
edittext1.scrollTo(0, y);
```

because `scrollTo(x,y)` measures x and y in pixels, and you were sending it the number of lines. `getLineHeight` returns the number of pixels per line, so 
lineHeight * lineCount = total pixel height.

(Also, I'm guessing you wanted the LineCount of edittext1, not of its parent layout.)